# I need a few answers about Lua, and posting copyrighted Src here and would like some feedback on my question before posting it

Tags: discussion

I just need some answers about how a game called Natural Selection 2 operates. Its written mostly in Lua. I have prepared the following question but I'd like some feedback on it. My account has been blocked a few times for not abiding by the question formatting rules; so you know my concern.

I would also like to know if its okay to post the source of a file from the game. I understand that under US copyright law a person can cite the author and it will still be legal if the original work is quoted.

Here is my question:

I'm attempting to document the code of Natural Selection 2 which is
 written in Lua. I know some things about Lua though I don't have the
 entire language under my belt yet. I would like to know where the game
 scripts are getting their functions from. For example there's a few
 lines like so:

```
Script.Load("lua/Shared.lua")
```

Its obvious to me what is happening here. However due to my desire to
 document the entire game I need to know where this object "Script" and
 its member function `Load()` are from. There are no `require()`
 function calls at the beginning of the file or elsewhere. I do not own
 the source code for this game and the copyright belongs to Unknown
 Worlds Entertainment. I will leave some of the source here so that I
 can show everyone what I mean.

```
[Code removed]
```

is from a link through `MainMenu.lua` which loads the Script

[Code removed]

Decoda is the script editing software for NS2. I do know and
understand the Shared, Predict, Server, and Client objects are VM's
("Virtual Machines" for the uninitiated) which I assume run the game
on whichever computer they're running on.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about quality of a question belonging on SO, and not an issue with the operation or functionality of SO.

Comment: I don't see why this is off-topic here; asking whether a question is on-topic on SO is clearly within the remit of MSO, and I'd rather people learnt how to ask good questions here rather than in the furnace.

Comment: @ben I'm with you on that - improving the quality of questions is exactly what we want the Q-ban to do and this is a very constrictive way of dealing with it.

Comment: @Ben you know what else this question would be a good fit for? *\*cough\** [Stack Overflow Academy](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/72987/stack-overflow-academy?referrer=bFkThEZ9P7sjquHM9dKpFQ2) *\*cough\** ...

Comment: That's quite a good idea of Shog's @cupcake... It might almost be better as the antithesis of SE, wanting "too localised" questions.

Comment: @Ken This is not off-topic in any way, shape or form.

Comment: @Cupcake: Oooh we'd better be able to close questions on SO with some new "reason" that links straight to a post on SOA ;) "Closed as violating Academy rule #363"

Comment: Ironically, posting the source here will break the same agreements/laws (if any) as posting it on the main site. But we'll ignore that for now.

Comment: `I understand that under US copyright law a person can cite the author and it will still be legal if the original work is quoted` What does citation have to do with copyright laws?? An author's name is not copyrightable in any law I heard of. Posting the source code is another matter. Just because you cite it doesn't mean you haven't infringed on a copyright.

Comment: It seems to me the source code you are looking at is not necessary to answer your question.  If you phrase the question as "There are variables/functions in the Lua code for Natural Selection 2  that I can't find a definition for anywhere in the Lua source." anyone with Game Engine / Lua experience should be able to explain it.

Comment: Regarding the copyright issue; should I edit it out of the question now?

Answer (score 26):

The question is: has the author of the game published the source openly online?

If so, then you are within your rights to (re)publish or quote snippets when you are talking about it, especially when you are being quite above-board with it. You don't have to quote a lot - just enough to illustrate your question.

However there are another couple of options. If the author has expressly stated that they deny republishing rights then you could:

- link to the location where the author published
- or create a demo version of the code that illustrates your problem

Note that this can be a tricky thing - even if you do have rights (i.e. fair use provision under copyright) it doesn't necessarily stop lawyers from trying to pick at you or the owner of the code getting snarky.

The SE rules stipulate that you must have the right to publish any code you put in your question - **so if you have any doubts about your rights *then don't publish it***, instead make a demo version as mentioned above.

Comment: The down votes here genuinely confuse me. I'm wondering; does anyone have a guess why this was down voted?

Comment: @AndrewBarber downvoted as well. This answer only focuses on the copyright problems, but that's mostly irrelevant as slugster ignores that the question OP wants to post to SO is crap anyways - too broad, unclear, not obvious that OP has the required minimal understanding, etc. Basically, as far as I can grok it he's trying to reverse-engineer a game by reading some .lua files and wondering why there are some things and functions that are not defined in lua; which is simple as they're probably defined in the non-lua part of the game instead (and the how is unanswerable without the game source).

Comment: @l4mpi ok, I can see that point. I think in this case, though, this is a decent answer to a bad question.

Comment: It's a ±1 from me for that reason. An excellent section on copyright, but missing all the other sections ;)

Comment: Also note that slugster is openly teaching the OP to link to a full-project-sized block of _off-site_ code in his question, which we strongly and expressly discourage.

Comment: @Braineeee why is that insulting? I certainly didn't write it to insult you; in fact, that you want to understand (==reverse-engineer) the code is primarily a good thing. You just seem to be lost and missing the broader context. For one thing, the game's source is of course **not** just lua files, the engine is written in C/C++, and the game logic is scripted in lua _on top of the engine_. And that the question you want feedback on is unfit for SO as it's broad, vague, and displays a severe lack of knowledge is simply fact. I don't sugarcoat my feedback, if it offends you, don't read it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm simply answering the part of the question that is on topic for Meta - the rest needs to be posted on SO and take its chances. Unfortunately the question has been edited to make it more suitable for SO - the Meta part of it has become obscured. I'm not really advocating linking to large code listings off site - that should be a last resort, only if it's necessary.

Comment: @l4mpi Yes he has lots more to learn, but everyone has to start somewhere. Whether or not his question survives on SO is separate to the Meta question he asked. Unfortunately he mixed a lot of the proposed SO question in and that just confused things - but at least he's making an effort to find out where he stands before he breaks any rules.

Comment: @slugster I have no problem with him asking on meta, and I agree that asking here first is better than simply posting to SO without regard for the rules or community consensus. But stating that "Whether or not his question survives on SO is separate to the Meta question he asked" is contradictory, as he _specifically asks for feedback on his question_ - thus I downvoted your answer, as you completely ignore this part of his question; which is IMO at least as important as the copyright part.

Comment: @Braineeee: Can't down. SO is not a helpdesk and not a place where we should do everything humanly possible in the name of "help", ignoring any other factors whatsoever.

Comment: (To be fair, the comments here are a bit rude. "the question OP wants to post to SO is crap" - come on, seriously? The OP is reading these, you know...)

Comment: (@AndrewBarber I downvoted; the rest of my comment explains why.) Why would whether it's been published online or not doesn't change what the author's copyright on it would be?  If a book has been published in paper, but not electronically, there are still fair use quotations as well as improper reproductions.  (There is, of course, an advantage in the electronic/online publication, in that you can link to the online version to provide readers with greater context.)  Just because something's been published online doesn't mean that you can reproduce more of it than if it hadn't been.

Comment: @l4mpi This answer ignores the fact that the original question was crap because the questioner never asked about the quality of the question but only if it is OK to publish code snippets on the SO question.

Comment: @Brandin `I have prepared the following question but I'd like some feedback on it [...] I would also like to know if its okay to post the source` - These are two questions, one about the copyright and one about the question in general. This is spelled out in the title as well.

Comment: @l4mpi I agree it is crap by the way.